# How to use Autohotkey hotstring in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autohotkey

I can use it in other applications such as notepad, but it just won't work with vs code.It seems that there is a bug or did I do any thing wrong?
For example

```
::td::TODO
```

and every time I will get a different result:

[AHK BUG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tL3z.gif)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug from an extension
[Markdown All in One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyXJ0.png)
It is fine when I disabled it.

Answer (score 1):

Autohotkey workaround:

```
::td::{Sleep 100}TODO
```

Increase the 100ms as the hotstring (to delete) becomes larger. On my machine I could expand hotstrings with length 25 in 250ms. Your mileage may vary.

[Relevant Github Issue](https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown/issues/200)

I replaced my hotstrings en masse with the following regex:

Search: `::[a-z0-9_-]+::(?!\{)`
Replace: `$0{Sleep 250}`

---

In the Github issue Mehul has another workaround:

```
:SE, K1:td::TODO
```

This does not require a variable amount of ms as it will always work regardless of hotstring length but it took so long to print the replacement text I found it unworkable.

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't want to disable the `Markdown all in one` extension.

Going off of @Laoujin's workaround, this works perfectly for me.

The below hotstring will type out the current date when type qcd (not terminating character). If VSCode is active, it waits 100 milliseconds.

```
:*:qcd::
FormatTime, timeString, , MM/dd/yyyy
typeText(timeString)
return


typeText(text) {
  IfWinActive, Visual Studio Code
    Sleep, 100

  SendInput, %text%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue of the vs code extension `Markdown all in one`, see [issue 200](https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown/issues/200).

You don't have to disable the `Markdown all in one` extension. Simply deleting the key binding `markdown.extension.onBackspaceKey` in vs code resolve this problem, but at the cost of losing some of the list editing features of `Markdown all in one` extension (which I haven't felt of).

See [known issue](https://markdown-all-in-one.github.io/docs/guide/compatibility.html#non-keyboard-ime) for more details.